# Radius of convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> We want the radius of convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}z^n$

We know that $R = \frac{1}{L}$ where

$$L = \limsup |e^{-n^2}|^{1/n} = \limsup |e^{-n}| = \limsup \frac{1}{e^n} = 0$$

So the radius of convergence is $R = \infty$ and the series converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Is this an appropriate approach to the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works! The coefficients $e^{-n^2}$ decrease very rapidly, so that series converges anywhere on the complex plane.

If you want to be convinced of that, you could just prove that the series of the absolute values,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}|z|^n,
$$
converges using the old tools for nonpower series analysis. This series has positive terms (being a series of absolute values), so you can use the good old root criterion, obtaining something like the proof that you gave.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{-n^2}|z|^n)^{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{-n}|z|).
$$
This limit is zero for any value of $z$, so the series converges for any value of $z$, as you just proved.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x$ is so much larger
than any power of $x$ that

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^c}z^n
$
converges for any
$z$ when
$c > 1$.

If
$0 < c < 1$,
the series converges when
$|z| < 1$.

If $c = 1$,
the series converges when
$|z| < e$.